# pytz and Centos and mysql - django

Tags: python, mysql, django, centos, pytz

The admin view of blog objects lists blog objects sorted by date.  When the page is open (on development server), this error is returned:

`Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.dates(). Are time zone definitions and pytz installed?`

The error message also includes: `Server time: Tue, 3 Dec 2013 16:58:33 -0500`

`pip install pytz` returns: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytz-2013.8-py2.6.egg`

In settings.py:
`TIME_ZONE = 'America/Detroit'`

On the CentOS machine in /etc/sysconfig/clock:
`ZONE='America/Detroit'`

When I start the development server, it shows:
`December 03, 2013 - 17:01:23`

MySQL field datatype is `DATETIME` and includes data like `2013-12-03 20:48:09`

In admin.py I added

```
import pytz
from pytz import *
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Not sure what else to check--all the above looks correct.  Why would django complain about pytz?

thanks!

Comment: You add timezones in MySQL? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need add timezones in MySQL. 
Documentation -  [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html)